# Creating a single view based on selection from two Parameters

Tags: tableau-api

I created two Parameters .

1. Select Metrics   -->  It lists down two values "Sales" ,"Profit"
2. Select Dimension -->  It lists down two values "Category", "Sub-Category"

Look at Screen shot below

[image]

Now I am looking for a single bar chart based on selection from these two parameters .

Let's say if i select "Sales" from Select Metrics and Category from Select Dimension then a view  for Sales in terms of  each category needs to be displayed .

Similarly if i select "Profit" from Select Metrics and Category from Select Dimension then a view for profit in terms of each category needs to be displayed..

likewise Sales By sub-category and Profit by Sub-Catgeory

I also created a calculated field

```
if     [Select metrics] ='Sales'   and  [Select dimension] = 'Category' then [Category]
ELSEIF [Select metrics] ='Profit'  and  [Select dimension] = 'Category' then [Category]
ELSEIF [Select metrics]  ='Sales' and [Select dimension]   ='Sub-Category' then [Sub-Category]
ELSEIF [Select metrics]  ='Profit' and [Select dimension]   ='Sub-Category' then [Sub-Category]END
```

But if i select Sales from Select metrics then this view is not changing .

How do i make this view to be reflected for my respective selection from two parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your column is having `sum(PROFIT)` you need to create 2 different calculated fields.

1 . metrics which should be =

```
if [Select metrics] ='Sales' then [Sales Column]
elseif  [Select metrics] ='Profit ' then [Profit Column]
end
```

2. Dimension ->

if [Select dimension]='Category' then [Category]

elseif [Select dimension]='Sub-Category'

then [Sub-Category]

end
Put the metric field on column and dimension on rows.
Now check and see if it is working.

Comment: Yes, As per your suggestion i created two calc. fields (i.e) one for dimension and one for metrics.. It worked.. Thanks much for your help...